# Unit Testing Interactions of methods in the same class in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following code

```
public ClassToTest : IClassToTest
{
    private readonly DBRepository rep;

    public bool MethodA()
    {
        //Some logic
        var result=MethodB();
        //Do some logic against result;
    }
    public ResultType MethodB()
    {
        return Rep.GetResult();
    }
}
```

If I want to Unit testing *MethodA*, what is the best practice to test the interaction between *MethodA* and *MethodB*? I am thinking to test *MethodA* like testing *MethodB* by mocking Database dependency *Rep*, just like *MethodA* has the following implementation

```
    public bool MethodA()
    {
        //Some logic
        var result=Rep.GetResult();
        //Do some logic against result;
    }
```

But it is not intuitive by checking the logic in the code and the test method.  I am looking for a solution similar to the one mentioned here for Java.

[unit testing composite service methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421265/unit-testing-composite-service-methods)

But It is not working for C#.

One extra question, What if *MethodB* is private, does it make any difference for the Unit testing strategy?

Update: prefer not to change the structure of the class. like not making MethodB as virtual or Move the MethodB out of the class into another test

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to test the *interaction* between `MethodA` and `MethodB`, you want to test that `MethodA` will return the expected `bool` result, given some context.

The fact that `MethodA` calls `MethodB` is not germaine to this test; but the fact that `Rep.GetResult()` will at some point be called is.

As you mentioned, you can mock the dependency `Rep`, so it won't matter whether `MethodB` is `public` or `private`.

1. Mock and inject the dependency
2. Call `MethodA`
3. Assert against the result

Comment: Thank you, Jay. Guess this is the answer. I am just worry about the test method is not following the logic of the **MethodA**. which may have less readability if the Method to test has complicated logic.

Comment: @zhaow Can you explain what you mean when you say the test method is not following the logic MethodA?

Comment: So the calling hierarchy is MethodA => MethodB => Rep.GetResult(), In unit testing for MethodB, I already tested MethodB=>Rep.GetResult(). Then when I test MethodA, I feel it is more clear and intuitive to test MethodA => MethodB. But if the logic of MethodB and MethodA are not complicated, testing MethodA=>Rep.GetResult() is clear too.

Comment: @zhaow Remember that what you really care about is the behavior of the system, not implementation. You want to know if the database is returning value1, `MethodA` will return `false` and if the database is returning value2, `MethodA` will return `true`. Testing the internal call hierarchy within a class doesn't really demonstrate behaviour so much as implementation. When you test behaviour, your tests are more maintainable because you can often refactor the code without breaking the tests. Indeed, the tests become your gauge of whether the refactoring was correctly done.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. It totally making sense and cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You want to isolate your methods that you test, that is, you want to mock MethodB while testing MethodA, and vice versa.

Also, there is a testing paradigm to test the contract (or interface) of classes. In this paradigm, you wouldn't worry about non-public non-virtual methods. I tend to mock as much as I can.

I recommend you use a mocking framework (smug, rhino mocks, moq, easymock) Smug being the coolest, but it is not yet complete - I'll just show you the code below (this is how it would work without a mocking framework to help you).

```
public enum ResultType
{
  Ok,
  NotOk,
}

public abstract class DBRepository
{
  public abstract ResultType GetResult();
}

public class ClassToTest
{
  public DBRepository Rep { get; set; }

  public virtual bool MethodA()
  {
    //Some logic
    var result = MethodB();
    //Do some logic against result;

    return result == ResultType.Ok;
  }

  protected virtual ResultType MethodB()
  {
    return Rep.GetResult();
  }
}

public class DBRepositoryMock : DBRepository
{
  public ResultType FakeReturn { get; set; }
  public override ResultType GetResult()
  {
    return FakeReturn;
  }
}

public class ClassToTest_MethodA : ClassToTest
{
  public ResultType MethodB_FakeReturn { get; set; }

  protected override ResultType MethodB()
  {
    return MethodB_FakeReturn;
  }
}

// tests

[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
  ClassToTest mock = new ClassToTest_MethodA();
  (mock as ClassToTest_MethodA).MethodB_FakeReturn = ResultType.Ok;
  Assert.IsTrue(mock.MethodA());
}

// or using injection
[TestMethod]
public static void Test2()
{
  var obj = new ClassToTest();
  obj.Rep = new DBRepositoryMock { FakeReturn = ResultType.NotOk };
  Assert.IsFalse(obj.MethodA());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer. I just updated my question, I prefer not to change the existing structure of the class. I feel there is no need to make the method virtual for testing purpose.

Comment: :( You picked the other answer, you'll see my answer actually provides 2 solutions, not just one. My 2nd solution is to inject the DBRepository value, the first was for those that feel they need to test each method individually. It's preference.

Comment: sorry about that. I do appreciate your answer. And it is a good answer too and provide two correct solutions. But Jay's answer make it clear what I should do for the best when unit testing. Although you provided two solutions, but at that time I was not clear that it is a preference problem. That's why I pick Jay's answer. Thanks again for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestMethod]
public void MethodAReturnsTrueGivenSomeDataAndCondition()
{
IDBRepository mockRepo = new Mock<IDBRepository>(); //Create a mock of your repository call
ClassToTest subjectToTest = new ClassToTest(mockRepo.Object); //Inject the dependency

mockRepo.SetUp(r=>r.GetResult()).Returns(someSampleTestData); //You're setting up the object that might return you true to return when mock repo will be called, by default it returns the default or null usually

var result = subjectToTest.MethodA();
mockRepo.Verify(r=>r.GetResult(), Times.Once); //Make sure your repo method was called
Assert.IsTrue(result); 

}
```

Something like this, using Moq as a sample mocking framework.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can just directly copy it. :)